# Insert a line, and color to border for grid views in a KV file

Tags: python, kivy

How can I insert a line(seperator) between widgets, and also color border for grid views in a KV file:

`TextBox` is just a `TextInput` box with `max_chars` feature.

Current KV file:

```
<Label@Label>
    text_size: self.size
    valign: 'middle'

<ContactFrm>
    padding: 5,5
    orientation: 'vertical'
    #row_default_height: '36dp'
    #cols:1 
    #spacing: 0,0

    GridLayout:
        cols: 4     
        row_default_height: '32dp'
        row_force_default: True
        spacing: 10,0
        size_hint_y: None
        #height:34

        Label:
            text: 'Name'
            size_hint_x: 0.5

        TextBox:
            id:name
            max_chars:35

        Label:
            text: 'Contact Name'
            size_hint_x: 0.5

        TextBox:
            id:contactname
            max_chars:35

    GridLayout:
        cols: 4     
        row_default_height: '32dp'
        row_force_default: True
        spacing: 10,0       
        size_hint_y: None
        #height: 36             

        Label:
            text: 'Mobile 1'
            size_hint_x: 0.5
        TextBox:
            id:mob1
            max_chars:35
        Label:
            text: 'Mobile 2'
            size_hint_x: 0.5
        TextBox:
            id:mob2
            max_chars:35
        Label:
            text: 'Landline'
            size_hint_x: 0.5
        TextBox:
            id:land1
        max_chars:35
    Label:
        text: 'E-mail'
        size_hint_x: 0.5
    TextBox:
        id:email1
        max_chars:75

GridLayout:
    row_default_height: '32dp'
    row_force_default: True
    spacing: 10,0
    cols: 4     
    size_hint_y: None
    #height: 36

    Label:
        text: 'Street 1'
        size_hint_x: 0.5
    TextBox:
        id:street1
        max_chars:75
    Label:
        text: 'Street 2'
        size_hint_x: 0.5
    TextBox:
        id:street2
        max_chars:75
    Label:
        text: 'Area'
        size_hint_x: 0.5
    TextBox:
        id:area
        max_chars:75
    Label:
        text: 'City'
        size_hint_x: 0.5
    TextBox:
        id:city
        max_chars:35
    Label:
        text: 'District'
        size_hint_x: 0.5
    TextBox:
        id:district
        max_chars:35
    Label:
        text: 'State'
        size_hint_x: 0.5
    TextBox:
        id:state
        max_chars:35
    Label:
        text: 'Zip Code'
        size_hint_x: 0.5
    TextBox:
        id:zipcode
        max_chars:10
BoxLayout:
```

I am new to both python and kivy, so above code might be a little naive, please advice where all I can improve also.  Thank you.

Final Code I used with modifications, so thickness can also be provided:

```
<Seperator@Widget>:
    id: separator
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 6
    thickness: 2
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: .24, .65, .94
        Rectangle:
            #pos: 0, separator.center_y
            pos: self.pos[0], separator.center_y
            size: separator.width, self.thickness
```

Comment: I'm new in Kivy but: did you search in documentation (or in internet) whether there is widget which you could use as separator ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am new in Kivy but I think you could add a normal `Widget` as a separator and draw a rectangle on its canvas.

Something like this gives me a red line - see image below:

```
    Widget:
        id: separator
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 6
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 1., 0., 0.
            Rectangle:
                pos: 0, separator.center_y
                size: separator.width, 2
```

[image: grid layout with red line]

---

I think you could use canvas (or canvas.before) in GridLayout to draw a border (using rectangle or two - external with color of border and internal with color of background) but probably you will need to make (somehow) some margin to show that border.

---

**EDIT:**

First solution was with constant thickness.

For different thickness you need some calculation.
I add `margin` to make that calculation.

```
<Separator@Widget>
    size_hint_y: None
    thickness: 2
    margin: 2
    height: self.thickness + 2 * self.margin
    color: 1., .0, .0
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: self.color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.x + self.margin, self.y + self.margin + 1
            size: self.width - 2 * self.margin , self.thickness
```

BTW:
I use `+1` in `pos` because it looks better (but I don't know why).
I add left and right margin.

[image: grid layout with many separators]

Comment: That worked for a seperator, and for border I suppose I have to enclose another widget to get the effect.  Also for spacing issues I replaced you line 'pos: 0, separator.center_y' with this 'pos: self.pos[0], separator.center_y'

Comment: I think you could even use `separator.x` or `self.x` in place of `self.pos[0]` to make it more readable.

Comment: BTW: `center_y` is good for `thickness: 2` - for other thickness you need some calculation. See in my answer.

Comment: Nice, but I need to learn more to understand the way kivy behaves, I am from, VB, visual studios used to handle much of my work:P, and WPF was very very clear compared to kivy.  But after some experience, I can say, we should not compare these bith, they are different.

Comment: hello sir, what if I want to add line separator in between columns of gridlayout having cols = 4 and rows = 2

Answer (score 2):

You can also just set spacing for your grid layout and draw a rectangle as background. Like this:

```
GridLayout:
    spacing: 10

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.3, 0.69, 0.31, 1.0
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
```

That will look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work, because everything becomes green (and not only the background).

I even tried to make sure to add my GridLayout (with a Blue background this time) inside a box layout with the Green background.

The expectation would be that of a clear contrast between a Green under layer with my all Green widgets on top (similar to the print you shared, but Blue instead of White).

That's not what happened, as it still becomes an all Blue. It seems whatever is the latest color added, that becomes THE backgroud color for the whole window.

Here is the .kv file:

```
BoxLayout:

<BoxLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.3, 0.69, 0.31, 1.0
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    SettingsGridLayout:

<SettingsGridLayout>:
    orientation: "lr-tb"
    spacing: "20dp"
    padding: "30dp"
    cols: 2
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    Label:
        text: "Rows:"
        #text_size: self.size
        #halign: "left"
        #valign: "middle"
        color: 1, 0, 0, 1
        size_hint: .3, None

    SizeSelectionSpinner:
        size_hint: .7, None
        height: "40dp"

    Label:
        text: "Columns:"
        text_size: self.size
        halign: "left"
        valign: "middle"
        color: 1, 0, 0, 1
        size_hint: .3, None

    SizeSelectionSpinner:
        size_hint: .7, None
        height: "40dp"
```

And here is the resulting screen:

[image]